# Make an api using django-rest-framework and pandas

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am planning to make an api using django-rest-framework and pandas. My task is to use the already existing api of my project and collect the data and convert it to pandas dataframe and make my own api using django-rest-framework.I am not able to understand should I use my own django models and use them with already existing models or should I don't use my models and use the already existing api data models. How should I implement this using django-rest-framework. Can someone help me iam a bit confused.